# How to add and execute windows environment variable in alias

Tags: windows, cmd, alias, conemu, cmder

Windows 10. cmder/clink environment.

For example I want to add alias for fast history watching:

`cat %CMDER_ROOT%\config\.history` - work if i copy-paste it to console.

But this line at aliases.config `history=cat %CMDER_ROOT%\config\.history` - doesn't work correctly.

Output is: `cat: '%CMDER_ROOT%\config\.history': No such file or directory`.

So how I can force this alias to be executed before "been eaten" by cat (^-^)

Comment: Unfortunately, [wishful thinking does not cause features to spring into existence](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120927-00/?p=6483).

Comment: @Maximus The problem not to store alias, but to expand environment variable from that file. When I store alias with windows environment variable as at my example, it doesn't expanded to full path

Comment: seems it was bug at clink, that was already fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was bug at clink parser, that was already fixed

Answer (score 0):

Expanding environment variable names between `%` symbols is a cmd.exe and Windows Explorer shell feature. Whatever program is reading your aliases.config file would need to do likewise.